# Ragged arrays: find shortest row and expand it to size of the longest row (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

If I have a ragged array and I need to expand the shortest row to the length of the longest one, is there any way for me to actually change the 2d array? I understand how to find the shortest and longest rows.

I understand you cannot change the size of an array, and typically you would make a method expandArray() where you would return an expanded copy of the array.

Either it is:

1. Make a copy of the 2d array and replace the shortest one with the new  expanded copy
2. Make an expanded copy and somehow do a[i][] = new expanded array

Is #2 possible? I need to do this without pre-made methods (code it myself line by line)

Thank you.

Comment: Could you give an example of your array and what you want to do with it?

Comment: Say I have a[5][] with different row lengths. If the shortest is a[1][1] and the longest is a[4][5], I want to make the length of a[1] the same as a[4].

Comment: Okay! You need one loop where you find your shortest and your longest array. After that you can copy the max-array in the place of the min-array as @Anubian Noob already suggested

Comment: How could I do this without Arrays class methods?

Comment: then you could create a new array in the place of the old one, with capacity max-size and then copy the values one-by-one into it?

Answer (score 0):

First thing we need to do is find the length of the longest row:

I'm assuming `arr` is an initialized 2D ragged array.

```
int length = 0;
for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    if (arr[i] > length)
        length = arr[i];
```

Now we need to expand all the arrays to the length of the longest row. We can use `Arrays.copyOf`.

```
for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    arr[i] = Arrays.copyOf(arr[i],length);
```

If you don't want to use libraries (which will make your code much less efficient) you can manually copy everything over:

```
for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    int[] newArr = new int[length];
    for (int j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
        newArr[j] = arr[i][j]
    arr[i] = newArr;
}
```

Note that `Arrays.copyOf()` calls `System.arrayCopy()` which copies the entire array as a block of memory, increasing performance.